Unmatched Route screen - in expo file bases routing
In Expo router file based routing, if I name a directory like this tabs rather this (tabs) it shows "Unmatched Route" screen but doesn't log any error or warning. And I don't want to name some directories with parenthesis (). anyone have any idea what's the problem or if I am doing something wrong?
The folder structure is something like this:
  app/
     _layout.jsx
     tabs/
         index.jsx
         profile.jsx
         _layout.jsx
     about/
         index.jsx
         _layout.jsx


app/ _layout.jsx:
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar translucent={true} />
      <Stack
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" /> // doesn't work when: <Stack.Screen name="tabs" />
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}


